# Magento 2 Category list API with layered navigation

Tags: magento2, api

Is there any API we can get category product listing with Layered Navigation.

I want to use in Mobile Application.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you find any solution for this ? The closest answer i found is https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262086/80513