# Magento 2 api - How to get layer navigation filters available in rest api?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, rest-api

I have someone issue in api magento 2. I need get layer navigation data available in product collection ( current category , search product ) but I don't know magento 2 api available it or not . I have create new custom api using Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver but it not work . Any one can help me ?

[image: i need get this data in rest api]

thanks guys

Comment: @Nguyen Can we add additional filter in it for example : if someone clicked on a particular brand then other brand should be remove from layer navigation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 methods to achieve this

**First one**

Filter.php (api model)

```
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request 
        $request){
            
                $this->_request         = $request;
        }


/**
     * Retrieve filterlist
     *
     * @api
     * @return array
     */
    public function retrieve(){     

        $category = $this->_request->getParam('categoryId');

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

        $appState = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
        $layerResolver = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
        $filterList = $objectManager->getInstance()->create(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
                [
                    'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
                ]
            );      

            $layer = $layerResolver->get();
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
            $maxPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
            $minPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();  

        $i = 0;
       foreach($filters as $filter)
       {
           //$availablefilter = $filter->getRequestVar(); //Gives the request param name such as 'cat' for Category, 'price' for Price
           $availablefilter = (string)$filter->getName(); //Gives Display Name of the filter such as Category,Price etc.
           $items = $filter->getItems(); //Gives all available filter options in that particular filter
           $filterValues = array();
           $j = 0;
           foreach($items as $item)
           {
               

               $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
               $filterValues[$j]['value']   = $item->getValue();
               $filterValues[$j]['count']   = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
               $j++;
           }
           if(!empty($filterValues) && count($filterValues)>1)
           {
               $filterArray['availablefilter'][$availablefilter] =  $filterValues;
           }
           $i++;
       }  

       
        echo json_encode($filterArray);
        exit;

    }
```

**Sample out put of this code will be:**

```
{
    "availablefilter": {
        "Climate": [
            {
                "display": "All-Weather",
                "value": "202",
                "count": "1"
            },
            {
                "display": "Cool",
                "value": "204",
                "count": "1"
            }
        ],
        "Manufacturer": [
            {
                "display": "Azzedine Alaïa",
                "value": "216",
                "count": "1"
            },
            {
                "display": "Balenciaga",
                "value": "217",
                "count": "1"
            }
        ],
        "Material": [
            {
                "display": "Cotton",
                "value": "33",
                "count": "1"
            },
            {
                "display": "Nylon",
                "value": "37",
                "count": "1"
            }
        ],
```

**Second method**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $productAttributeCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productAttributeCollectionFactory = $productAttributeCollectionFactory;
    }
 
    public function getFilterableAttributes()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection $productAttributes */
        $productAttributes = $this->productAttributeCollectionFactory->create();
        $productAttributes->addFieldToFilter(
            ['is_filterable', 'is_filterable_in_search'],
            [[1, 2], 1]
        );
 
        return $productAttributes;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the 2nd method? How can it filter product within *CategoryId*.

Comment: @NamTrung  You can get all the filterable attribute list by Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory class.

The result will be all those attributes which have, Use in Layered Navigation status are Filterable (with results) or Filterable (no results).

You need to create __construct( ) function for define dependency of Class.

Comment: Now call a function in template file by iterating over a loop to fetch each attribute code,
$getAttributes = $block->getFilterableAttributes();
 
    foreach ($getAttributes as $attribute) {
        echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();echo "<br>";
    }

Comment: Result would be something like this:  manufacturer
    color
    activity
    style_bags
    material
    strap_bags
    features_bags
    gender
    category_gear
    size
    eco_collection
    performance_fabric
    erin_recommends
    new
    sale
    format
    style_bottom
    style_general
    sleeve
    collar
    pattern
    climate

Comment: I'm working with REST API and trying to implement `Use In Layered Navigation` for mobile app. In your 1st method, i saw you need category_id but in 2nd method  you only filter those attribute have `is_filterable` has value 1 or 2 and `is_filterable_in_search`. So those accepted filter not related to specified category, right?

Comment: if you are writing  a api i would suggest you to go with first method. I have been following frst method for a while and its working. I haven't tried second method with api.

Comment: Hi @NID - I tried first solution. But it always gives all filters. Could you please suggest if there is any order to call the Model? I am currently calling it after collection is loaded when we call /rest/default/V1/products

Comment: @NID How to filter product collection with given attribute value. it can be multiple value of colors, size, ram etc... I'm stuck on this. I've create filter api its working for root category but not for all. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299135/filter-collection-by-config-product-attribute-value-in-magento-2-programmaticall

Comment: @all How to apply filters on configurable products using API ?

Comment: @NID Can we add additional filter in it for example : if someone clicked on a particular brand then other brand should be remove from layer navigation?

Comment: @Kanika Your requirement differs from the normal filters working. so you will have to customize as per your need.

Comment: @NID could you please guide me or do you have any source/link ?

Comment: I'm playing with first method you shared, If I pass category and check max and min price it returns max from whole products, I want max price for specific category, Like, If I've category having 3 products and I pass that category `$layer->setCurrentCategory($categoryId);` then get filters and print max price it doesn't display max price from these 3 products why ? It display max price at global level I've a product which is having 780 USD, Max price print this value this is worng righht ?

Comment: Is there an option to get all available filters per store view for a category? E.G: some store view may not have the attribute for e.g `Color=123` filter because the or a product(s) are not available in a specific store view !

Comment: How to implement above file.Does i need to create a module or just can add above file.Where i will be add.

Comment: @Anees Creating a separate module for api functionality is the right way. you could define your endpoints in your webapi.xml

Comment: I am getting this error Report ID: webapi-5fd209d0b0d81; Message: Notice: Undefined variable: filterArray in

Answer (score 3):

Unless your email address ends in '@magento.com', you should not be using Object Manager in your code. No ifs, no buts. This is how I went about achieving this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterListFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as layerResolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;

class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList
     */
    protected $filterableAttributes;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
     */
    protected $layerResolver;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterListFactory
     */
    protected $filterListFactory;

    /**
     * Your constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList $filterableAttributes
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param FilterListFactory $filterListFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        FilterableAttributeList $filterableAttributes,
        layerResolver $layerResolver,
        FilterListFactory $filterListFactory
    ) {
        $this->filterableAttributes = $filterableAttributes;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->filterListFactory = $filterListFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get filters for a category page.
     * @param string $category_id
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getCategoryFilters(string $category_id): array
    {
        $returnFilters = [];
        $filterableAttributes = $this->filterableAttributes;
        $layerResolver = $this->layerResolver;
        $filterList = $this->filterListFactory->create(['filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes]);
        $layer = $layerResolver->get();
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category_id);
        $layer->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter("visibility", ["neq" => Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE])
            //optional to exclude product attributes of non visible products
            ->addAttributeToFilter("status", ["eq" => Status::STATUS_ENABLED]);
            //optional to exclude product attributes of disabled products
        foreach ($filterList->getFilters($layer) as $filter) {
            $values = [];
            foreach ($filter->getItems() as $item) {
                $values[] = [
                    "display" => strip_tags($item->getLabel()), //strip_tags is optional, but there's HTML in some of my labels
                    "value" => $item->getValue(),
                    "count" => $item->getCount()
                ];
            }
            if (!empty($values)) {
                $returnFilters[] = [
                    "attr_code" => $filter->getRequestVar(),
                    "attr_label" => $filter->getName(),
                    "values" => $values
                ];
            }
        }
        return $returnFilters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer.

Comment: Unless your email address ends in '@magento.com', :D

Comment: This answer is according to Magento standard approach & it's working fine!!!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works fine, but it is also counting the products with visibility hidden, even added the line addAttributeToFilter("visibility", ["neq" => Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE])

Please let me know if you have any solution for this issue.

Comment: If I were you @KishorThummar I'd check the visibility of $item as it's being looped through in the foreach - I'd be surprised if it were Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE though

Answer (score 2):

Get request value in json format like below

```
{
        "category_id":"36" //pass category which you want
}
```

below is the Filterattributes.php (api model)

```
<?php
    namespace HIT\Customer\Model;
    use HIT\Customer\Api\FilterAttributesInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;
    
    class FilterAttributes extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements FilterAttributesInterface
    {
        
    
    
        public function __construct(
           
        ){
           
        }
    
        /**
         * Returns greeting message to user
         *
         * @api
         * @param string $name Users name.
         * @return string Greeting message with users name.
         */
        public function filterAttributes() {
           
            $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $post = json_decode($json);
            
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($this->_request->getParam($post->category_id));
            $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);
    
            $appState = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
            $layerResolver = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
            $filterList = $objectManager->getInstance()->create(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
                    [
                        'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
                    ]
                );      
    
                $layer = $layerResolver->get();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
                $maxPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
                $minPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();  
    
            $i = 0;
            $filterAttrs = [];
           foreach($filters as $filter)
           {
                $values = [];
                $attr_code = (string)$filter->getRequestVar();
                $attr_label = (string)$filter->getName();
                $items = $filter->getItems(); //Gives all available filter options in that particular filter
               foreach($items as $item)
               {
    
                    $values[] = array("display"=>strip_tags($item->getLabel()),
                                        "value"=>$item->getValue(),
                                        "count"=>$item->getCount());
               }
               if(!empty($values) && count($values)>1)
               {
                   $filterAttrs[]=array("attr_code"=>$attr_code,
                                    "attr_label"=>$attr_label,
                                    "values"=>$values);
               }
    
           }  
    
    
           if(count($filters)>0){
            $data['status'] = "true";
            $data['filters'] = $filterAttrs;
           }else{
            $data['status'] = "false";
            $data['msg'] = "No Filters Found";
           }
     
       
    
             echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );// str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($data)); 
            exit();
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Can we add additional filter in it for example : if someone clicked on a particular brand then other brand should be remove from layer navigation?