# Magento 2 - Custom API to get layered navigation

Tags: magento2, api, layered-navigation, magento-2.2.5, customapi

In magento 2.2.5 Enterprise edition

I am trying to get layered navigation using custom API.

I got solution form here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262086/31910

my code is this: **Please ignore ObjectManager it is only for testing purpose**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

    //$appState = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
    $layerResolver = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
    $filterList = $objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
        [
            'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
        ]
    );

    //$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $layer = $layerResolver->get();
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
    $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);

    $data = array();
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        if ($filter->getItemsCount()) {
            $data[] = $filter;
        }
    }

    return $data;
```

The problem is, I am getting this error after applying this code:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.created_in'
> in 'where clause', query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1,
> 2)) / 10000) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM
> `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`\n INNER JOIN
> `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON
> cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND
> cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='46'\n INNER
> JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON
> e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND
> stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id =
> 1\n INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5e05a53f383179_70162465` AS `search_result`
> ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE
> ((stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)) AND (e.created_in <=
> '1573154701') AND (e.updated_in > '1573154701') AND ( e.website_id =
> '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL)
> GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10000) + 1 ORDER BY
> (FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10000) + 1) ASC

I don't know why it is adding `(e.created_in <= '1573154701')` in where clause

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi. Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your Rest Api model file use this below code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Layered;

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

class Filters implements Customer
{

    public function orders($id)
    {
        $category = $id;

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

        $appState = $objectManager->getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
        $layerResolver = $objectManager->getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
        $filterList = $objectManager->getInstance()
            ->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class , ['filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes]);

        $layer = $layerResolver->get();
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
        $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
        $maxPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()
            ->getMaxPrice();
        $minPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()
            ->getMinPrice();

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($filters as $filter)
        {
            //$availablefilter = $filter->getRequestVar(); //Gives the request param name such as 'cat' for Category, 'price' for Price
            $availablefilter = (string)$filter->getName(); //Gives Display Name of the filter such as Category,Price etc.
            $items = $filter->getItems(); //Gives all available filter options in that particular filter
            $filterValues = array();
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($items as $item)
            {

                $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
                $filterValues[$j]['value'] = $item->getValue();
                $filterValues[$j]['count'] = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
                $j++;
            }
            if (!empty($filterValues) && count($filterValues) > 1)
            {
                $filterArray['availablefilter'][$availablefilter] = $filterValues;

                $i++;
            }
        }

        return $filterArray;
        exit;
    }

    exit;

}
```