# Rest Api add additional attribute filter in Layer navigation API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, layered-navigation

I have successfully created Layer navigation REST API using given solution on this question [Magento 2 api - How to get layer navigation filters available in rest api?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262086/28348) 
However I want **if someone clicked on a particular brand then other brand should be remove from layer navigation** 
Currently it's return result based on category id, I would like to add more filter like Brand, color etc

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request 
        $request){

                $this->_request         = $request;
        }


/**
     * Retrieve filterlist
     *
     * @api
     * @return array
     */
    public function retrieve(){     

        $category = $this->_request->getParam('categoryId');

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

        $appState = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
        $layerResolver = $objectManager->getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
        $filterList = $objectManager->getInstance()->create(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
                [
                    'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
                ]
            );      

            $layer = $layerResolver->get();
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            $filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
            $maxPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
            $minPrice = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();  

        $i = 0;
       foreach($filters as $filter)
       {
           //$availablefilter = $filter->getRequestVar(); //Gives the request param name such as 'cat' for Category, 'price' for Price
           $availablefilter = (string)$filter->getName(); //Gives Display Name of the filter such as Category,Price etc.
           $items = $filter->getItems(); //Gives all available filter options in that particular filter
           $filterValues = array();
           $j = 0;
           foreach($items as $item)
           {


               $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
               $filterValues[$j]['value']   = $item->getValue();
               $filterValues[$j]['count']   = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
               $j++;
           }
           if(!empty($filterValues) && count($filterValues)>1)
           {
               $filterArray['availablefilter'][$availablefilter] =  $filterValues;
           }
           $i++;
       }  


        echo json_encode($filterArray);
        exit;

    }
```