# What is the best way to get available filter in magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

What is the best way to get available filter in magento 2 REST API.
I want to create Layered navigation using Layered navigation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I want to get available filter attribute for like category page side bar

Comment: For example::https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262052/magento-2-api-how-to-get-layer-navigation-filters-available-in-rest-api